# Cannot choose free dyno anymore on heroku

Tags: heroku

since some time I cannot choose the free dyno option anymore on heroku and wondering why that is? I could not find any hints in the docu

[image]

here on the left I could choose the free dyno option in the past. Now its gone.
When I simply switch off the dyno, the app does not work anymore:

[image]

How can I get back to free dyno usage on heroku for my app?

Answer (score 0):

The app referenced above is part of heroku teams, this is why free dynos are not possible there.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-teams#supported-dyno-types